# Why is the data in row truncated when importing CSV in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, csv, replace, import, warnings

I have a table in Mysql that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `overig`.`test`(
`ID` INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Order_ID` DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
`Price_total` DECIMAL(12,2),
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

I want to import the following CSV:

```
Order_ID;Price_total
145131343;118,35
145131349;79,35
```

I load the CSV data into the MYSQL table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE `overig`.`test` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
    (`Order_ID`, @Price_total)
    SET `Price_total` = 0 + REPLACE(@Price_total, ',', '.');
```

The response:

```
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                          |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'Price_total' at row 2 |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Why do I get this warning? What's the difference between the value of row 2 and 3?

The result is okay, but I want to understand the warning.

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+-----------+-------------+
| ID | Order_ID  | Price_total |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | 145131343 |      118.35 |
|  2 | 145131349 |       79.35 |
+----+-----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I change the order in the csv to:

```
Order_ID;Price_total
145131343;79,35
145131349;118,35
```

I get the following:

```
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                          |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'Price_total' at row 1 |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I import the data like this, then there are no warnings:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test4.csv' INTO TABLE `overig`.`test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (
`Order_ID`, @Price_total)
SET 
`Price_total`  = REPLACE(@Price_total, ',','.');
```

Comment: please check what values have been imported by doing a select

Comment: LINES TERMINATED BY 'n' should be  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' or possibly  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Comment: Oddly I tested your code with your data and no warnings given and nothing inserted..

Answer (score 0):

If I redesign the table to:

```
CREATE TABLE `overig`.`test`(
`ID` INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Order_ID` DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
`Price_total` FLOAT(12,2),
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

So I changed the data-type from `DECIMAL` to `FLOAT` I don't get the warnings, although I don't exactly understand why.

If I change:

```
SET `Price_total` = 0 + REPLACE(@Price_total, ',', '.');
```

To:

```
SET `Price_total` = REPLACE(@Price_total, ',', '.');
```

Then it works also works without the warnings, but I added the above code to avoid getting warnings if `@Price_total` is empty. So then I have another problem.